# In relation to Cordova,When I am trying to install dialogs plugin and inappbrowser,I am getting "Registry Returned Error404"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Registry Returned 404 for GET on https:registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova,InAppBrowser/Dialogs[IMAGE PLEASE CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr6mm.png)

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the cordova plugins might not work.So getting them right from reliable source is very important.In this case.The correct plugins can be found from cordova.io 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs and the second one is cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser or cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git